# BASH associative arrays and indirect expansion

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I want to use indirect expansion with bash associative arrays. Let say i have variable varname, that contains array name (and some key):

```
varname="array"
key="some_key"
```

I can check if array is declared:

```
if [ -z ${!varname+x} ];
```

And declare it:

```
declare -Ag "$varname"
```

But I don't know how to:

1.Check if associative array contains key:

```
if [ ! ${!varname[key]+_} ]; # doesn't work
```

2.Add key to array:

```
$varname[$key]=0 # doesn't work
```

3.Increase element:

```
(('++'$varname'[$key]')) # doesn't work
```

Is this even possible and if so how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456950/bash-indirect-reference-to-an-associative-array

Comment: `bash` 4.3 allows you to check for the existence of the key with `[[ -v $varname[$key] ]]`.